# How to display input buttons on one line in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a small little Bootstrap panel, and I have 3 Bootstrap buttons in the panel at the bottom. What I'm trying to do is make all the buttons be on one line and have a small gap, not bunched together. Here's what I have right now, and here's what it's doing:

```css
.recent 
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 500px;
}

.recent input
{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="recent">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><center><span class="label label-danger">Recent</span></center></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>- Aurora, Colorado : Blah Blah Blah</p>
                                <input type="button" value="View all" onClick="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="button" value="Last 24 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <input type="button" value="Last 48 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-warning">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What's happening is this:

[image: Screenshot of three buttons where the first two are right next to each other and the third one is below them.]

https://gyazo.com/46b7c219adc26be516475c8f3b4d803d

Is there any way to make them stay on one line, or would I have to make the column larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make the column width wider. Since you're using `col-lg-3` class, the last button is wrapping to the next line.  Try changing it to a larger column (i.e. `col-lg-6`).  To answer the second part of your question, you can add a CSS rule like `.btn {margin: 0 5px;}` if you want some space between the buttons.

Comment: Another question. What's the difference between col-lg-3 and col-sm-3, etc? I tried messing around with lg, md, and sm, but they are all the same size.

Comment: `xs` doesn't collapse at all.  The rest (`sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`) all refer to different breakpoints (i.e. when do multiple columns collapse and instead become multiple rows.  So if you want the columns to collapse to rows on all but the largest of screens, use `xl`.  If you want columns to be normal on all screens but small ones, use `sm`.  getbootstrap.com will be the best resource for you.

Comment: @DonaldCox - You can find examples of the use of these classes in their documentation of their grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

you can also achieve with out using `float` property. You use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`.

or you use 3 multiple division(.col-sm, .col-md, .col-lg) in `.row` or `.container`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<div class="recent">
                <div class="container">
                     <div class="row">

                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><center><span class="label label-danger">Recent</span></center></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>- Aurora, Colorado : Blah Blah Blah</p>
                                <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="button" value="View all" onClick="#" class="btn btn-primary"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="button" value="Last 24 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-danger"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="button" value="Last 48 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-warning"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points.

1. Why are you giving 500 margin right to recent class? it will create problem in responsiveness. Even if you are targeting only desktop screen it is not good practice. 500 margin forcing to reduce width of recent.
2. you are using col-lg-3 It might be fine to use col-lg-3 for larger screens more than 1200px wide.. for small screens there are col-md-3, col-sm-3 and col-xs-3
3. Give a little margin-right to buttons so that they have a little space.

```css
.recent 
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.recent input
{
    float: left;
}
.m-right{
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="recent">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><center><span class="label label-danger">Recent</span></center></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>- Aurora, Colorado : Blah Blah Blah</p>
                                <input type="button" value="View all" onClick="#" class="btn btn-primary m-right">
                                <input type="button" value="Last 24 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-danger m-right">
                                <input type="button" value="Last 48 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-warning m-right">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm using the 500px margin to get it where I want, I'm not really aware of other methods right now.

Comment: Depending on your structure.. you can give specific widh and display inline block. 2nd option is to give float left to recent class. If you can share mockup. I can give you better idea for basic structure of your html.